# synchronous in-memory LRU cache map

Tags: scala, caching, lru

I am looking for a simple LRU cache in Scala that works in-memory. It's used only on the Swing event dispatch thread, and so I don't want futures, like in [the Spray caching code](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-caching/src/main/scala/spray/caching/LruCache.scala).

Basically I need a `Map[Int, java.awt.Paint]` with a bounded size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of something implemented in Scala, but you can use Java libraries such as [concurrentlinkedhashmap](https://github.com/ben-manes/concurrentlinkedhashmap) or [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).

Comment: And soon [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) as the next generation of those libraries.

Comment: Caffeine looks pretty neat! I'm just frustrated as my project will still have to be compatible with JDK7 for a while :(